# Typescript: function with base type argument is incompatible with a function with subtype argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

why is a function with a base type argument incompatible with a function with a subtype type argument in a typescript?

The link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-SwpoAJgAzIHA0N4aAFTCwBwjE0AJz9ZDBkY6wIcA3IMgaEiYiAUAAW0DZ8npIC4johWWgAEZ2GCUuka1Brsg9h1Dmh1L7zmAhjdKHIgA)

```
interface SD_UI_Field {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

interface SelectInput extends SD_UI_Field {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  items: [];
}

interface FieldResolver {
  // The DataType type parameter is used to specify that the fieldData argument must be a subtype of SD_UI_Field.
  <DataType extends SD_UI_Field>(
    fieldData: DataType,
  ): void;
}

// Error: 
// Type '(fieldData: SelectInput) => void' is not assignable to type 'FieldResolver'.
//   Types of parameters 'fieldData' and 'fieldData' are incompatible.
//     Type 'DataType' is not assignable to type 'SelectInput'.
//       Property 'items' is missing in type 'SD_UI_Field' but required in type 'SelectInput'.(2322)
// input.tsx(9, 3): 'items' is declared here.

const resolver1: FieldResolver = (fieldData: SelectInput)=>{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

its a little messy typing functions with interfaces, so one option its using 'type' word, and define the funcion inside

```
interface SD_UI_Field {
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

interface SelectInput extends SD_UI_Field {
  type: string;
  name: string;
  items: [];
}

type  FieldResolver<DataType extends SD_UI_Field> = (fieldData: DataType) => void;

const resolver1: FieldResolver<SelectInput> = (fieldData: SelectInput) => {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, you aren't getting the task right.  The question is how  to get example:

```const resolver1: FieldResolver<SD_UI_Field> = (fieldData: SelectInput) => {}```
working ?